# Git lfs (Large File Storage) says lfs managed files are modified after a git lfs pull

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I have a working copy of a repository that uses git-lfs to store some large files. I have git-lfs binary installed, but may not have run "git lfs install" inside of the working copy. When I want to update my local working copy after additions of lfs files, I execute these commands:

```
git pull
git lfs pull
```

That worked fine as long as lfs files were being added. Then the repository had some lfs files that were modified and when I ran `git pull` I got the error message:

```
Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge
....
....
```

And it listed out all of the lfs files that were going to be modified by the pull.

Since then, I ran `git lfs install` inside the working copy and it worked fine, but `git status` still lists all those files as being modified and a `git pull` gives me the same error.

My question is basically, what are the right steps for updating my working copy if I'm using lfs? How do I clean up this sticky situation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out that running `git lfs install` inside the working copy was half the solution. The second half was to run `git reset` inside of the working copy which:

- left the large files in place
- let git know that they were not actually dirty and were just fine

And now it seems that I no longer need to explicitly do the `git lfs pull` to get the latest large files. The first `git pull` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, before I git clone, I do `git lfs install` first and then `git clone`. Everything is solved! I think this question is very important and common there are tons of GitHub discussions without showing the true solution (at least not shown in a glance)! Thanks for your answer greggles.

Comment: If you have not yet done a git clone then this seems like a decent solution. My case was having already done a git clone and needing to pull in lfs-managed files.

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly the same problem with files having an upper case file extension when working with Windows (git version 2.31.1 & git-lfs/2.13.3) and Linux (git version 2.25.1 & git-lfs/2.9.2).

My `.gitattributes` contained `*.jpg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text` with a lower case `*.jpg` and I committed files under Windows with an upper case file extension like `test.JPG`. After cloning the repository on a Linux system, the images with an upper case extension (`.JPG`) only held the reference where as the images with a lower case file extension (`.jpg`) got cloned as expected.
After executing a `git lfs pull` on the Linux system the images where located correctly on the file system but now they showed up as **Modified**.

**The solution** was to configure Git to ignore the case on Linux by running:
`git config --global core.ignorecase true`