# git lfs says file modified after git lfs install

Tags: git-lfs

*(this question appears to be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685689/git-lfs-large-file-storage-says-lfs-managed-files-are-modified-after-a-git-lfs), but the solution does not work here and is in fact part of the question)*

My remote repository contains some file pushed under  `git lfs`. If I start with a brand new local repository and then execute:

```
git lfs install
git pull
```

The files will remain pointers even though common knowledge indicates that  `git pull` should pull them at this point. If I execute instead:

```
git lfs install
git lfs pull
```

Then the files will be fully downloaded but will appear as modifications. Why isn't `git lfs install` sufficient for `git pull`  to download all the files in this case? Why do the files appear as modified after a `git lfs pull` following a `git lfs install`?